# Passing HashSet<string> by reference

Tags: c#

Is it possible to pass a HashSet by reference to a function? This is my code currently.

**Main**

```
this.scrapeFriends(startUsers, userIDs, 100);
```

**Function**

```
private void scrapeFriends(StringCollection startUsers, ref HashSet<string> userIDs, int p)
{
    // Do something
}
```

If I remove the ref it works. If I add it, it don't and it won't compile.

Comment: You're probably misunderstanding `ref`.

Comment: Did you remember to put in the ref key word in front of userIds  when calling the scrapeFriends method from Main?

Answer (score 10):

You're *always* passing a `HashSet<T>` by reference since it is a reference type.

The `ref` keyword is there for you to pass the *variable* by reference.

Basically:

- With or without `ref`, you can change the contents of the `HashSet<T>`
- With the `ref` keyword, you can replace the `HashSet<T>` instance with a *different* instance, and have the calling code be aware of this (you're modifying the variable passed to the method)
- Without the `ref` keyword, if you replace the instance with a different instance, that change only has effect inside the method being called, the code that called it still has the old reference

The reason the code is not compiling is that if you make a parameter to a method a `ref` parameter, you have to call it with the `ref` keyword as well, so change your calling code to this:

```
this.scrapeFriends(startUsers, ref userIDs, 100);
                               ^^^
                                |
                                +-- add this
```

Answer (score 3):

In order to make this compile you need to add `ref` at the callsite

```
this.scrapeFriends(startUsers, ref userIDs, 100);
```

However I do want to ask why you are doing this?  `HashSet<T>` is a reference type in .Net and hence a copy of it's not passed to every function.  Each function will refer to the same `HashSet<T>` instance (but through a different copy of the reference).  The `ref` causes the reference to be passed by reference which is almost certainly not needed here

Answer (score 1):

There are few situations where you need to pass around a mutable reference type(such as `HashSet<T>`) around by reference. Are you sure this is one of them? In particular the method can add new items to the set without using `ref`. You only need `ref` if you want to change which set this points to in the first place. It's unlikely that you want that here.

The reason why your code doesn't compile is that for `ref` parameters you also need to specify `ref` at the call site:

```
this.scrapeFriends(startUsers, ref userIDs, 100);
```

But as I said, it's unlikely that you want this.

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned in other answers, to ensure the code compiles, you need to add `ref` at the calling site, as below.

`this.scrapeFriends(startUsers, ref userIDs, 100);`

To give a bit more context, HashSet is a reference type in C#. When you pass it to the method **without ref** , the address of the memory location where HashSet is stored is passed. This allows you to only add/ remove elements from HashSet.

However, when you use `ref` while calling the method, the memory address of the location where variable is stored is passed. This allows you to point the variable to a new location i.e. create a new instance of HashSet and manipulate it.